# How to integrate google api Spreadsheet callback url on my production server

Tags: java, spring-mvc, google-sheets

I am reading data from google spreadsheet API using java. I am able to read on my local machine and the URL getting below for auth2:

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&client_id=679281701678-iacku5po12k0if70abstnthne9ia57kg.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http://localhost:39740/Callback&response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets

My callback URL is

http://localhost:62238/Callback?code=4/k6rwrqBFTJ310Yhy9EBpIA7eH9PqL-HXwC3hi9Q0How#

However, when I am deploying my war on the production server so I am not able to see callback function.

If any one knows about this please suggest to me how to integrate on the production server.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you integrate with any OAUTH enabled google api. You need to provide the restrictions on google dev console like authorized origins and authorized redirect uris. I think you might have provided different port from your local than what is running in your production in your authorized origins, that is why it is not able to connect from your production server but it is able to connect from your local. you can cross check once.

Comment: I have added authorized origins and authorized redirect uris both. but always my URL take localhost:(autogenerate port).

Comment: your call back url is always taking localhost:autogenerated port ?
please paste the call back url for which you are having issue.. Also pls check that you send the same value as part of the redirect uri which you have regsitered on the google dev console..

Comment: I am getting localhost for below url 

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&client_id=679281701678-iacku5po12k0if70abstnthne9ia57kg.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http://localhost:39740/Callback&response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets

Comment: if you notice your callback url is "redirect_uri=http://localhost:39740/Callback" which you are sending as part of the rest call to spread sheet api. Now you have to check if your production service has the running instance on same localhost:port combinations. If your port is different than 39740 in your production then you will not get callback to your production server. 
Another thing you can do, you can register more than one redirect uri on google dev console. and send the uri on which your actual production service is running as redirect uri then you will be able to get callback in prod.

Comment: When you are sending the request to spreadsheet api using below url :

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&client_id=679281701678-iacku5po12k0if70abstnthne9ia57kg.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http://localhost:39740/Callback&response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets

change your redirect_uri value in the above url to the same value which you have configured on google dev console.

Comment: How I can change localhost to my google dev console rediect_uri ? I am always getting localhost in URL.

Comment: When you send the request to spreadsheet api you set the value of redirect_uri in the URL on which you send the request. 
"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&client_id=679281701678-iacku5po12k0if70abstnthne9ia57kg.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http://localhost:39740/Callback&response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"

if you see this URL you are sending a redirect_uri parameter in this URL.
So you have to change value of this redirect_uri to exactly same as google dev console value.

Comment: I am using below code , can you please guide me how I can change:

 InputStream in = ReadDataFromGoogleSheet.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secret.json");
  GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

Comment: GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));
  // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
  GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY,
      clientSecrets, SCOPES).setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY).setAccessType("online").build(); 
  Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
  System.out.println("Credentials saved to " + DATA_STORE_DIR.getAbsolutePath());

Comment: Hi Pushendra Pal please guide for the same, need your guidance urgent

Comment: Hey @Shubhamkapoor it's been a while since this issue was discussed. Can you pls explain the issue once to bring me to the same page?

Comment: @PushpendraPal I found the solution, thanks for the help